# Using session data ion custom permissions Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-sessions, django-permissions

I want to validate session data in custom permission, when i tried to access session data inside permissons it is showing None.Please help on this.

```
class IsEmployee(permissions.BasePermission):
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    
    if (request.session.get(request.user) and request.session[self.request.user.email].get("project_id")) is not None:
        project_id = request.session.get("project_id")
        if Employee.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user,
                                   project_id=project_id, status="A", project__status='A'):
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Result throws None

Comment: result none means - the Employee.objects.filter(bla bla ) not exists. this code works normally.

Comment: i printed result.session in custom permission it returnef session object.Whereas in views it returned  dict object

Comment: Are you using DRF and session authentication?